# VLC Player Staying On Top Of The Opened Applications On Desktop

Tags: vlc

I want my VLC player not to minimize while I am on the windows of other applications. Whenever I click another window the VLC player window will go behind the my currently clicked window but I want it to resist being on top.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

VLC > Video menu > Float on top...

[image]

Comment: I believe this will only make VLC Float on Top when videos are playing. The application itself won't float on top, e.g. if audio files are played.

Comment: My bad, the solution does work but you have to restart application.